# Find two strings next to a keyword with re in python

Tags: python

I need to find two strings next to a keyword. Here is an example string

```
\plottwo{image1}{image2}
```

the keyword is \plottwo and the correct result is

```
[image1, image2]
```

I know that if there is only one string next to the keyword I can use

```
re.findall('\plottwo.*?{(.*?)},text)
```

how can I extend this to two strings?

Comment: Please show an example of the input

Comment: Is this TeX? You might be able to parse this mostly-correctly, but you'll probably want to use something other than regex, and [parsing TeX completely correctly is Turing complete](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/is-there-a-bnf-grammar-of-the-tex-language).

Comment: hm user2357112... I would have thought this is a well defined problem? Why do you say it can only be made mostly-correct?

Comment: @carl: It *can* be done completely correctly, but doing so is an extremely complex job. It's certainly much more than a 1-liner regex can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this matches exactly two image strings:

```
import re

matcher = re.compile(r"""\\plottwo   # The literal \plottwo
                         {           # Opening brace for the first image group
                          (          # Start the first capture group
                           [^}]+     # Match anything OTHER than a closing brace
                          )          # End the first capture group
                         }           # Closing brace
                         {           # Opening brace for the second image group
                          (          # Start the second capture group
                           [^}]+     # Match anything OTHER than a closing brace
                          )          # End the second capture group
                         }           # Closing brace
                      """, re.VERBOSE)

print matcher.findall('\\plottwo{image1}{image2}')
```

If you wish to capture either one or two image strings, make one of the capture groups optional:

```
import re

matcher = re.compile(r"""\\plottwo   # The literal \plottwo
                         {           # Opening brace for the first image group
                          (          # Start the first capture group
                           [^}]+     # Match anything OTHER than a closing brace
                          )          # End the first capture group
                         }           # Closing brace
                         (?:         # Non-saving group that we can make optional
                            {        # Opening brace for the second image group
                             (       # Start the second capture group
                              [^}]+  # Match anything OTHER than a closing brace
                             )       # End the second capture group
                            }        # Closing brace
                         )?          # End the non-capturing group
                      """, re.VERBOSE)

print matcher.findall('\\plottwo{image1}{image2}')
print matcher.findall('\\plottwo{image2}')
```

But to echo one of the comments, regex is typically not the best way to do complex parsing jobs (and sometimes even simple parsing jobs :-).

Comment: what would you suggest instead of regex?

Comment: @carl It depends on what you're trying to parse. :-)

Comment: just for completeness your solution gives a list of tuples instead of a list... so I added list(chain(*result))... with that it works perfectly

Comment: Yes, findall returns a list of all sets of matched groups in the input text. There is at least one Python LaTeX parser out there: https://github.com/tiarno/plastex - I've not used it personally so I can't comment on it's usefulness.